# running live and test node simultaneously

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, testnet, bitcoin-cli

it took me 4 days to fully synchronize my node, but its finally running and i can create wallets etc..

I wanted to experiment with some transactions on testnet, so need to either change my config or create a separate instance.

But I don't want to lose my synchronized live node, so what's the best strategy to switch to testnet while still being able to switch back?

```
# [core]
datadir=/mnt/volume-nyc1-03/Bitcoin
dbcache=2000
txindex=1

# [rpc]
# Accept command line and JSON-RPC commands.
server=1
# Username for JSON-RPC connections
rpcuser=bitcoin
# Password for JSON-RPC connections
rpcpassword=sayblockchainonemoretime
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=x.x.x.x/x (ip masked) 
# [wallet]
# Do not load the wallet and disable wallet RPC calls.
disablewallet=0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run both at the same time:

```
$ bitcoind -daemon
$ bitcoind -testnet -daemon
```

Then you can issue commands on either using:

```
$ bitcoin-cli <commmand>
```

or

```
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet <command>
```

The blockchains are stored in `./bitcoin/blocks` for mainnet and `/bitcoin/testnet3/blocks` for testnet.

**Update**: With the `bitcoin.conf` updated in the question remove `rpcport=8332`, so it doesn't try to use the same port for mainnet and testnet RPC.

**Update 2**: With 0.17 release, it is now possible for a single configuration file to set different options for different networks in `bitcoin.conf`:

```
main.uacomment=bitcoin
test.uacomment=bitcoin-testnet
regtest.uacomment=regtest
```

For more information, see the [0.17.0 Release Notes](https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/0.17.0/)

Comment: $ bitcoin-cli getblockcount: 538439

Comment: $ bitcoin-cli -testnet getblockcount: 538439

Comment: looks like its going against main

Comment: hmm i do see the testnet3 folder under bitcoin now ..

Comment: Hmm. might be an issue with your `bitcoin.conf`

Comment: seeing this in debug.log 
2018-08-25 21:08:24 Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2018-08-25 21:08:24 Using 2 threads for script verification
2018-08-25 21:08:24 scheduler thread start
2018-08-25 21:08:24 Binding RPC on address :: port 8332 failed.
2018-08-25 21:08:24 Binding RPC on address 0.0.0.0 port 8332 failed.
2018-08-25 21:08:24 Unable to bind any endpoint for RPC server
2018-08-25 21:08:24 Error: Unable to start HTTP server. See debug log for details.

Comment: You might want to restart the daemons using `$bitcoin-cli stop` and `$bitcoin-cli -testnet stop` and then start again.

Comment: hmm tried that  but keep seeing *Binding RPC on address 0.0.0.0 port 8332 failed.*

Comment: Is something using that port?

Comment: so i set testnet=1 in bitcoin.conf which seems to work but now the main node is only running test i think. not sure if i can run both at the same time

Comment: Clear that line. If you only put the flag in the command line you can run both.

Comment: thanks! good to know :) for some reason w/out the line testnet wasn't working for me though.. keep getting that error in debug.log

Comment: Is it still not working? Would be helpful to post bitcoin.conf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82279/discussion-between-sonic-soul-and-jbaczuk).

Answer (score 0):

Run bitcoin.exe with conf and datadir params
And set the configuration file with testnet=1

Comment: i saw the config and am aware of these settings. but not sure how to ensure that my live blockchain stays untouched

Comment: By default the two networks will operate in different directories.