# how to make own coin with soft fork?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, litecoin, blockchain-fork, alternatives

What I am looking to do is soft fork on litecoin and create my own coin! I know that I need to make a node but I can't find any process that shows me how to create my own coin.

Answer (score 1):

Soft forks are generally used to upgrade an existing protocol in a backward compatible way. If you were to create a new coin you would need to hard fork the Litecoin protocol. How you do that depends on your motivation. If you just want to create a new coin to make money I would strongly advise against it. There are thousands of altcoins that have no unique selling proposition. It sounds like any coin you would make would also have no unique selling proposition.

If you want to experiment with your own network I would recommend looking into [Signet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98553/how-do-i-get-set-up-on-signet).

Comment: my problem statement is i want new coin but ledger should be same.(example if i fork litecoin and the address in litecoin ledger should be available in my new coin with same balance but name should be different).

User,A have LTC,1 same value should be available in NCoin,1 for the same address

Comment: Right, you get that with a hard fork.

Comment: how we can share ledger in hard fork ? as per my understanding for hard fork everything will be separate , network ,address prefix, all stuff can you please explain and provide me any guide line so i can start

Comment: @AwaisSakhi Could you clarify whether you mean that the ledger should continue to be the same after the split?

Comment: @MichaelFolkson yes same like what you are thinking . after splitting ledger should be same is that possible ?