# P2TR outputs on testnet

Tags: testnet, taproot

Anthony Towns [shared](https://twitter.com/ajtowns/status/1413432147247964166) that Taproot is activated on Testnet.

I am not sure if we can create P2TR outputs easily on Testnet right now based on this Q&A by Michael Folkson:

[How can I spend from a P2TR address on Signet with the Bitcoin Core wallet in 22.0?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/107452/how-can-i-spend-from-a-p2tr-address-on-signet-with-the-bitcoin-core-wallet-in-22)

I am interested in reviewing PR: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22421 and test `utxoupdatepsbt` on Testnet with PSBT spending Taproot outputs.

Comment: What is your question? Everything supported by its descriptors language should be easily doable with current Bitcoin Core master. You'll need to manually import the descriptor, and the scripts are fairly boring (only single-key, or 1-of-N, basically), but within those constraints it should work just fine as there are tests for it.

Comment: Question: How to create P2TR outputs on Testnet? For creating P2WPKH output, I just need to create new segwit address and send some bitcoin. Why is it different for Taproot? Importing descriptors is fine but import from where?

Comment: There is nothing specific to testnet about that; it's the same as on signet, or how it'll be on mainnet. You need to create the descriptor yourself because taproot descriptors aren't created by default yet (that'll only be added once it's active on mainnet). Import from where: write them yourself; the simplest would be `tr(xprv/*)` for some xprv. See https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md for more advanced ones.

Comment: Yeah only difference between testnet and signet re Taproot is that Taproot only recently activated on testnet but Taproot has been active on signet for months. Of course you need to get testnet Bitcoin and use -testnet flag but that isn't Taproot related