# Which exchanges or wallets offer the option to open Lightning channels with them at the time of writing?

Tags: lightning-network, ln-opening-channels

Which exchanges or wallets offer the option to open a channel with a Lightning routing node they operate at the time of writing (June 2023)? (I know Lightning Labs' [Pool](https://lightning.engineering/pool/) and [liquidity ads](https://medium.com/blockstream/lightnings-missing-piece-a-decentralized-liquidity-market-a0bb47534a4f) attempt to provide a solution to the inbound capacity problem but for now I'm just interested in outbound capacity.)

Of those that do are there any particular requirements (e.g. minimum channel capacity, uptime requirement)?

I understand that I could speculatively try Lightning nodes from [1ML](https://1ml.com/) or [Amboss](https://amboss.space/) but I'm capital and time constrained.

Also any exchanges or wallets offer the option to open signet channels with them at the time of writing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a draft answer. As always alternative answers are welcome.

[River](https://ln.river.com/) is advertising the option to open Lightning channels with them but recommends contacting them via email before doing this.

[Breez](https://doc.breez.technology/Open-a-Channel-with-Breez-Public-Node.html) has documentation on how to do this and has set a minimum 10 million satoshis (~$2,700) capacity. (I asked on the Breez Telegram why this minimum capacity was set and smaller channel opens were apparently causing routing failures. This seems like a problem with present day path finding algorithms as additional channels/routes are additive by definition and shouldn't increase routing failures.)

[Kraken](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/9829766858260-Connecting-to-Kraken-s-Lightning-node) has a minimum 1 million satoshis (~$270) channel capacity. (Thanks Poseidon for finding this)

> Also any exchanges or wallets offer the option to open signet channels with them at the time of writing?

I'm not aware of any. See this [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118400/can-you-help-me-get-started-running-a-signet-lightning-routing-node-with-intende) for guidance on setting up a routing node on signet.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/9829766858260-Connecting-to-Kraken-s-Lightning-node
I found this for Kraken Centralized Exchange.